# iptables for webserver (CentOS 5.6 with DirectAdmin 1.39.1)

Tags: apache, webserver, iptables, directadmin

I have been hosting a couple of websites on my dedicated machine. The OS is CentOS 5.6. Until now, I have been turning iptables off since it jsut blocked all web traffic. However, I see that this is not good and that I should enable the firewall. Unforunately, I have no idea how to do that, so I am asking here what good rules for my server should be. I have of course a lot of traffic going in and out.

A few things I run on the server - DirectAdmin - Apache - php - mysql - ftp - dns - other directadmin tools (like mail, etc).

It is pretty much a preinstalled version of DirectAdmin 1.39.1.

Please help me out.

Comment: You've got to be careful with this on a remote server, since it's possible to cut off access to it if you get your iptables rules wrong. It's worth reading this howto before you start:

[CentOS iptables HowTo](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/IPTables)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [ConfigServer Security & Firewall](http://configserver.com/cp/csf.html), it's a great and very complete firewall which works pretty well with Directadmin